# How to store a Geo Point in Backand

Tags: angular, geolocation, geopoints, backand

I want to have a location associated with all of the users of my app and to be able to filter what users see based on how close they are to each other. What is the recommended approach for this? I was disappointed to see that Backand does not seem to provide a "geopoint" data type out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered via the Backand docs that Backand does indeed provide this out of the box. The issue was I was trying to select the data type from the options offered in the visual model view which seems to be limited.

If I just edit directly in the actual model json view, I am able to specify the "point" type and that is exactly what I am looking for.